# How to tackle " heroku : command cannot found "

Tags: heroku

I have a problem when I type "heroku create" command

```
(venv)muzaffar@vaio:~/hellodjango$  heroku create
heroku: command not found
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download and install the [heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) and make sure `heroku` is on your `$PATH`.

Heroku normally is installed in `/usr/local/heroku` so you have to add `/usr/local/heroku/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

You can check your installation by running

```
 $ which heroku
 /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```

This checks your `PATH` for an executable file called "heroku", in my case it is found at `/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku`